# I would like to test the memory load on JUPYTERHUB

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am using a jupyter that operates as a POD in a k8s environment.

I want to test the kernel with Python code.

I would like to intentionally OOM the jupyter kernel.
The kernel does not die by using infinite loop/while.

I'd like to take a load test.
What source-code should be used to kill a jupyter kernel?

Comment: Getting something to die is not the same as load testing it. What kind of load are you looking to test? You could just allocate a honking big data structure, or keep increasing its size - but what exactly are you looking to show?

Comment: I just want to kill the kernel with Python code from Jupiter.  I'm just wondering how the log will look when the kernel dies.